# JavaScript Exporting a class definition

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

Can I export class definition in JavaScript?  For example,

in file "HelloWorld.js":

```
'use strict';

class HelloWorld {
  constructor(msg = 'Hello World~') {
    this.message = msg;
  }

  sayHi() {
    console.log(this.message);
  }
}

module.exports = HelloWorld;
```

Then in "index.js"

```
'use strict';
var HelloWorld = require('HelloWorld');

var myObj = new HelloWorld;
myObj.sayHi();
```

if I do "node index.js", then I got the error below:

```
  constructor(msg = 'Hello World~') {
                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/data/users/soltiho/fbsource/fbcode/video_templates/test_env/index.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

my node is v5.5.0

Comment: try removing the `{ }` around `HelloWorld` (why do you think these are necessary?)

Comment: removing { } changes the error to: </br>
**  constructor(msg = 'Hello World~') {
                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =**
</br>
the { } was added because the file may contain more things laster, so just added.. no meaning for now.

Comment: What version of node are you using? You should probably be running this through babel or something as well.

Comment: just update the question to remove destructing part.

Comment: The error seems purely relating to the default parameter.  if removing that default value and do "if (msg) { ... } else { ... }" instead, the flow works as expected.

Comment: Yep, default params are also not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

Node doesn't support destructuring (yet), and using destructuring would be wrong anyways. There is nothing special about importing/exporting a class. Import it like any other module:

```
var myValue = require('myVModule');
```